# subset using grep to include levenshtein distance?

Tags: r, string, match, character

I have two dataframes, with two character vectors of differing lengths that I would like to match, like so:

```
company.a <- c("heinz", "hawkings mcgill", "heinz ketchup", "heinz vinegars", "davis and smith", "dell computers", "dell", "O organics", "organics")

company.b <- c("heinz", "hawkings-mcgill", "oyster bay", "company x", "dell")
```

I would like to compare company.b to company.a, returning a vector containing the element from company.b that was matched to company.a.  I tried using the following code to subset the larger frame

```
match.comp <- subset(company.a, grep(paste(company.b, collapse = "|"), company.a, value = TRUE)).
```

However, what I get in return is an error stating 'subset' must be logical.  I would like the following result:

```
match <- c("heinz", "hawkings mcgill", "heinz", "heinz", "FALSE", "dell", "dell", FALSE, FALSE)
```

Given the error, clearly I'm missing something about grep or subset.  I have two questions:

1. Is grep the best way to do this?  Or is there another way?  I know about exact matching using the which(A %in% B) approach, but I cannot guarantee that the strings will be exact matches.
2. Grep will return the first match, but is there a way to extract all possible matches that were considered via, say, levenshtein distance?  I'm aware of the adist function in utils package, but I want to know if it can be combined with grep.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: `agrep`? Your desired output is unclear.

Comment: @alistaire thanks.  agrep looks good.  what I want is to return the matched  elements, if they work and if not, a logical value.  is this clearer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `adist` or `agrep`, but it's a very subjective process in terms of what costs and cutoff points will be. In this case, you could get the desired result with

```
d <- adist(company.b, company.a, partial = TRUE) 
d <- apply(d, 2, prop.table)    # working with proportions instead of costs can be useful

matches <- apply(d, 2, function(x){
    x <- setNames(x, company.b)
    names(which.min(x[x < 0.05]))    # set cutoff carefully
})
matches <- sapply(matches, function(x){ifelse(is.null(x), NA, x)})    # clean out NULLs

matches
## [1] "heinz"           "hawkings-mcgill" "heinz"           "heinz"           NA               
## [6] "dell"            "dell"            NA                NA
```

Comment: thanks this is a really excellent solution!  I really appreciate the help.  do you have any advice on procedures for figuring out the optimal cutoff points are for very large data frames?  or at least where i could look to figure it out?  thanks again.

Comment: It depends a bit what you know about the strings and what you want them to match with. Given the above example, the strings to match were mostly shorter, so I used `partial = TRUE`, which matches substrings without a character deletion cost, but you could set the deletion cost explicitly. Read the docs, and play around, but on data too big to inspect manually, I'd check error rates on a subset you _can_ inspect manually, akin to training error in model building.

Comment: can you explain a bit more about the cutoff?  does it match those with a proportion of same characters less than 5%?

Comment: In this setup, it's what determines which ones give you `NA`s. There's always some value with a minimum edit distance, but that value may be very high. Because of the `prop.table` call, the `0.05` really filters to values that contain less than 5% of the edit distance for all edit distances for that string, which is vaguely similar to `agrep`'s `max.distance` parameter. You can use edit distances directly instead of proportions if you like.

Answer (score 2):

This might partially satisfy your requirement:

```
library(utils)

company.a <- c("heinz", "hawkings mcgill", "heinz ketchup", "heinz vinegars", "davis and smith", "dell computers", "dell", "O organics", "organics")
company.b <- c("heinz", "hawkings-mcgill", "oyster bay", "company x", "dell")

limit <- 2

res <- sapply(company.a, function(wa) {
    d <- sapply(company.b, function(wb){
        adist(wb, wa)
    })
    d <- d[d<=limit]
    names(d)
})
```

The above code snippet will extract all matches in the second array, to each word in the first array. Here, two words are matched if the Levenshtein distance is atmost 'limit'.

Also note that some of the matches you have indicated above are not this simple. For eg, if "heinz" has to match "heinz ketchup", this will require a Levenshtein distance limit of 8, which will be too high in general. A more involved distance function will have to be constructed to deal with these cases.